# While Loops and If statements for my code

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I'm writing a program in which you encounter a monster, then giving the option to whether or not you want to attack or defend. When attacking the code seems fine but when I enter Defend the program would just close. Also when the players HP or monsters HP is <= 0, It would ask the user again if they would want to attack or defend then display the winning or losing message. I want it so that once it reaches <= 0 that it would only display the message.

http://pastebin.com/kU8jtQwb

```
    public string playerChoice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to Attack or Defend?");
        string playerchoice = Console.ReadLine();
        return playerchoice;
    }

    public void MonsterEncouter()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 101);
        int playerHealth = random.Next(50, 101);
        int playerAttack = random.Next(10, 31);
        string userInput = "";



        if (randomNumber >= 1 && randomNumber <= 24)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You've run into a goblin, an easy enemy");
            Console.WriteLine("Its HP is: " + randomNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Your HP is: " + playerHealth);
            Console.WriteLine("Let the battle begin!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (randomNumber >= 25 && randomNumber <= 49)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You've run into a dire wolf, a bit tough enemy");
            Console.WriteLine("It's HP is: " + randomNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Your HP is: " + playerHealth);
            Console.WriteLine("Let the battle begin!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (randomNumber >= 50 && randomNumber <= 74)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You've run into an orc, a hard enemy");
            Console.WriteLine("It's HP is: " + randomNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Your HP is: " + playerHealth);
            Console.WriteLine("Let the battle begin!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You've run into a giant, a very hard enemy");
            Console.WriteLine("It's HP is: " + randomNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Your HP is: " + playerHealth);
            Console.WriteLine("Let the battle begin!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        {
            userInput = playerChoice();
            if (userInput == "Attack")
            {
                while (userInput == "Attack" && playerHealth > 0 && randomNumber > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You attacked the beast!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You've dealt " + playerAttack + " damage");
                    randomNumber -= playerAttack;
                    Console.WriteLine("It's HP is: " + randomNumber);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    {
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("It fought back! It dealt " + playerAttack);
                        playerHealth -= playerAttack;
                        Console.WriteLine("You have " + playerHealth + " HP left");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        userInput = playerChoice();
                    }
                }
                if (randomNumber <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("The monster has been slain!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                if (playerHealth <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("You have been slain!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You lose");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            else if (userInput == "Defend")
            {
                while (userInput == "Defend" && playerHealth > 0 && randomNumber > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You are ready to defend!");
                    Console.WriteLine("The monster attacked!");
                    playerHealth -= 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("You blocked it's attacked and only lost 1 HP");
                    Console.WriteLine("You now have: " + playerHealth + " HP");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    userInput = playerChoice();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?  If you don't identify it specifically, you're likely to get useless and unrelated answers suggesting style changes (as seen below).

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of "outer loop". Your program structure is like

```
userInput = playerChoice();
if (userInput == "Attack") {
   while (userInput == "Attack") {
      ....
      userInput = playerChoice();
   }
} else if (userInput == "Defend") {
   while (userInput == "Defend") {
      ....
      userInput = playerChoice();
   }
}
```

When you first enter "Attack", the program goes in to the first `if` branch and stays there until you stop ordering more attacks. Then it leaves the `if` construct and terminates.

I think you want something like

```
userInput = playerChoice();
while (userInput == "Attack" || userInput == "Defend") {
    if (userInput == "Attack") {
       while (userInput == "Attack") {
          ....
          userInput = playerChoice();
       }
    } else if (userInput == "Defend") {
       while (userInput == "Defend") {
          ....
          userInput = playerChoice();
       }
    }
}
```

so that after the first "Attack" you can enter more "Attack" or "Defend" in any order.

Comment: Not sure why `while` loops inside the `if` make sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems here.

Get rid of the braces here:

```
Console.WriteLine();
{
   Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine("It fought back! It dealt " + playerAttack);
   playerHealth -= playerAttack;
   Console.WriteLine("You have " + playerHealth + " HP left");
   Console.WriteLine();
   userInput = playerChoice();
}
```

I am assuming you have those empty `Console.WriteLine();` calls so you have a blank line in your output. Instead, I'd suggest refactoring your previous lines to include an additional newline like this for example:

```
Console.Write("You have " + playerHealth + " HP left\n\n");
```

If you don't want to restructure your program flow, to fix your problem with being prompted after a player or monster has no HP left, add this if statement around your subsequent calls to `playerChoice()`:

```
if (playerHealth > 0 && randomNumber > 0)
{
     userInput = playerChoice();
}
```

I would also suggest renaming `randomNumber` to something more meaningful, something like `enemyHP`.

Regarding your problem with "Defend", have you debugged your code to see if that code branch is getting hit?